# Assignment makes pointer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, casting, warnings, variable-assignment

I am editing a quick sort code so that the values of low, high, and middle point to an array element instead of integers.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

void quicksort(int a[], int *low, int *high);
int split(int a[], int *low, int *high);

int main(void)
{
    int a[N], i;
    printf("Enter %d numbers to be sorted: ", N);
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    quicksort(a, &a[0], &a[N-1]);

    printf("In sorted order: ");
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void quicksort(int a[], int *low, int *high)
{
    int *middle;

    if (low >= high) return;
    middle = split(a, low, high);
    quicksort(a, low, middle - 1);
    quicksort(a, middle + 1, high);
}

int split(int a[], int *low, int *high)
{
    int part_element = *low;

    for (;;) {
        while (low < high && part_element <= *high)
            high--;
        if (low >= high) break;
        *low++ = *high;

        while (low < high && *low <= part_element)
            low++;
        if (low >= high) break;
        *high-- = *low;
    }

    *high = part_element;
    return *high;
}
```

I'm getting the error message:

```
qs.c:32:12: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 middle = split(a, low, high);
        ^
```

Can someone help me with this? Still a beginner at programming. All types of help are appreciated.

Comment: `middle` is a pointer; `split()` returns an integer.  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: `split` returns an int. `middle` is a pointer. Maybe just return `high` instead of `*high`?

Comment: `split()` returns an `int`. `middle` is an `int*`, so the warning is saying "you are assigning an int to a pointer. This is proabbly not what you meant to do".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this statement.

```
middle = split(a, low, high);
```

because `middle` is a pointer variable whereas `split` is a function which returns integer value not a pointer to an integer.

You are assigning integer value to a pointer variable `middle` .
You are not allowed to do that. :)

May be this will help you.

Comment: The function split should return a pointer to an integer, not an integer.

int *split(int a[], int *low, int *high);

Answer (score 0):

Change 'split()' to return an 'int *' instead of 'int'.

Change the last line of the 'split()' function from:

```
return *high;
```

to

```
return high;
```

Perhaps this would work better:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

void quicksort(int a[], int *low, int *high);
int *split(int a[], int *low, int *high);

int main(void)
{
    int a[N], i;
    printf("Enter %d numbers to be sorted: ", N);
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    quicksort(a, &a[0], &a[N-1]);

    printf("In sorted order: ");
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void quicksort(int a[], int *low, int *high)
{
    int *middle;

    if (low >= high) return;
    middle = split(a, low, high);
    quicksort(a, low, middle - 1);
    quicksort(a, middle + 1, high);
}

int *split(int a[], int *low, int *high)
{
    int part_element = *low;

    for (;;) {
        while (low < high && part_element <= *high)
            high--;
        if (low >= high) break;
        *low++ = *high;

        while (low < high && *low <= part_element)
            low++;
        if (low >= high) break;
        *high-- = *low;
    }

    *high = part_element;
    return high;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to change the 'int split' into 'int *split'.